# Displaying the output into html

Tags: powershell

I got a code for pinging the servers repeatedly. That best suits for my object. But the thing I want to display the result of the code to the HTML page. How can I do it?

```psh
Function Ping-Host {
    #Parameter Definition
    Param (
        [Parameter(position = 0)] $Hosts,
        [Parameter] $ToCsv
    )

    #Funtion to make space so that formatting looks good
    Function Make-Space($l,$Maximum) {
        $space =""
        $s = [int]($Maximum - $l) + 1
        1..$s | %{$space+=" "}

        return [String]$space
    }

    #Array Variable to store length of all hostnames
    $LengthArray = @() 
    $Hosts | %{$LengthArray += $_.length}

    #Find Maximum length of hostname to adjust column witdth accordingly
    $Maximum = ($LengthArray | Measure-object -Maximum).maximum
    $Count = $hosts.Count

    #Initializing Array objects 
    $Success = New-Object int[] $Count
    $Failure = New-Object int[] $Count
    $Total = New-Object int[] $Count
    cls
    #Running a never ending loop
    while ($true) {
        $i = 0 #Index number of the host stored in the array
        $out = "| HOST$(Make-Space 4 $Maximum)| STATUS | SUCCESS  | FAILURE  | ATTEMPTS  |"
        $Firstline=""
        1..$out.length | %{$firstline+="_"}

        #output the Header Row on the screen
        Write-Host $Firstline 
        Write-host $out -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Black

        $Hosts | %{
            $total[$i]++
            if (Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                $success[$i]+=1
                #Percent calclated on basis of number of attempts made
                $SuccessPercent = $("{0:N2}" -f (($success[$i]/$total[$i])*100))
                $FailurePercent = $("{0:N2}" -f (($Failure[$i]/$total[$i])*100))

                #Print status UP in GREEN if above condition is met
                Write-Host "| $_$(Make-Space $_.Length $Maximum)| UP$(Make-Space 2 4)  | $SuccessPercent`%$(Make-Space ([string]$SuccessPercent).length 6) | $FailurePercent`%$(Make-Space ([string]$FailurePercent).length 6) | $($Total[$i])$(Make-Space ([string]$Total[$i]).length 9)|" -BackgroundColor Green
            } else {
                $Failure[$i]+=1

                #Percent calclated on basis of number of attempts made
                $SuccessPercent = $("{0:N2}" -f (($success[$i]/$total[$i])*100))
                $FailurePercent = $("{0:N2}" -f (($Failure[$i]/$total[$i])*100))

                #Print status DOWN in RED if above condition is met
                Write-Host "| $_$(Make-Space $_.Length $Maximum)| DOWN$(Make-Space 4 4)  | $SuccessPercent`%$(Make-Space ([string]$SuccessPercent).length 6) | $FailurePercent`%$(Make-Space ([string]$FailurePercent).length 6) | $($Total[$i])$(Make-Space ([string]$Total[$i]).length 9)|" -BackgroundColor Red
            }
            $i++
        }

        #Pause the loop for few seconds so that output 
        #stays on screen for a while and doesn't refreshes

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
        cls
    }
}

Ping-Host '10.50.5.33'
```

Comment: Do you _really_ want your HTML to look exactly like is does currently in your output? I mean with each attempt shown as a separate row?

Comment: Yes, Matt. I want the exact output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConvertTo-HTML` is the simple answer here but first you need to have object based output. Currently you are just outputting text to the console with `Write-Host`. In order to make that work you are doing some fancy formatting footwork which unfortunately is useless if you are just going to be outputting to HTML.

You can change this if you want but I didnt like the idea of `while($true)` since it will break the natural creation of the HTML Table. Obviously you are entitled to do what you want but this should be a working version that almost duplicates what you have. If you want to do some formatting I recommend you look up html styles.

```psh
Function Ping-Hosts{
    param(
        [string[]]$hosts,
        [int]$MaxPings=100
    )

    # Hashtable that will record ongoing statistics
    $results = $hosts | ForEach-Object{
        @{
            $_ = @{
                Successes = 0
                Attempts = 0 
            }
        }
    }

    1..$MaxPings | ForEach-Object{
        # Ping each computer a maximumn number of times. 
        $pingCount = $_
        $hosts | ForEach-Object{
            # Clear output statistics
            $props = @{
                Host =  $_
                Status = "Down" # Assume it's down.
            }

            # Perform a single ping
            if (Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
                # Success
                $results.$_.Successes = $results.$_.Successes + 1
                $props.Status = "UP"
            }

            # Raise the number of attempts
            $results.$_.Attempts = $results.$_.Attempts + 1

            # Calculate statistics
            If($results.$_.Successes -eq 0){
                $props.Success = "{0:p2}" -f 0
            } else {
                $props.Success = "{0:p2}" -f ($results.$_.Attempts / $results.$_.Successes)
            }

            If($results.$_.Attempts - $results.$_.Successes -eq 0){
                $props.Failure = "{0:p2}" -f 0
            } else {
                $props.Failure = "{0:p2}" -f ($results.$_.Attempts / ($results.$_.Attempts - $results.$_.Successes))
            }
            $props.Attempts = $results.$_.Attempts

            # Output results. 
            New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample execution**

```
Ping-Hosts "c4222","C4280" | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

**Partial Sample Output**

```
<tr><th>Host</th><th>Status</th><th>Attempts</th><th>Failure</th><th>Success</th></tr>
<tr><td>c4222</td><td>UP</td><td>1</td><td>0.00 %</td><td>100.00 %</td></tr>
<tr><td>C4280</td><td>UP</td><td>1</td><td>0.00 %</td><td>100.00 %</td></tr>
<tr><td>c4222</td><td>UP</td><td>2</td><td>0.00 %</td><td>100.00 %</td></tr>
<tr><td>C4280</td><td>UP</td><td>2</td><td>0.00 %</td><td>100.00 %</td></tr>
```

**Closer to what you wanted**

If you want something other than this I would look into css formatting closer. This is not the way I would have done it but have a look. You are complicating things by asking for the extra headers as you go (maybe there is a better way but we are off topic enough for this question)

```
Function Ping-Hosts{
    param(
        [string[]]$hosts,
        [int]$MaxPings=100
    )

    # Hashtable that will record ongoing statistics
    $results = $hosts | ForEach-Object{
        @{
            $_ = @{
                Successes = 0
                Attempts = 0 
            }
        }
    }

    1..$MaxPings | ForEach-Object{
        # Ping each computer a maximumn number of times. 
        $pingCount = $_
        $hosts | ForEach-Object{
            # Clear output statistics
            $props = @{
                Host =  $_
                Status = "Down" # Assume it's down.
            }

            # Perform a single ping
            if (Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
                # Success
                $results.$_.Successes = $results.$_.Successes + 1
                $props.Status = "UP"

                # Set the backround color
                $colour = "#2FFF18"

            } else {
                # Set the backround color
                $colour = "#FF2020"
            }

            # Raise the number of attempts
            $results.$_.Attempts = $results.$_.Attempts + 1
            $props.Attempts = $results.$_.Attempts

            # Calculate statistics
            If($results.$_.Successes -eq 0){
                $props.Success = "{0:p2}" -f 0
            } else {
                $props.Success = "{0:p2}" -f ($results.$_.Attempts / $results.$_.Successes)
            }

            If($results.$_.Attempts - $results.$_.Successes -eq 0){
                $props.Failure = "{0:p2}" -f 0
            } else {
                $props.Failure = "{0:p2}" -f ($results.$_.Attempts / ($results.$_.Attempts - $results.$_.Successes))
            }

            # Output results. 
            $frag = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
            $frag -replace "<tr><td>","<tr bgcolor=$colour><td>"
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Call**

```
Ping-Hosts "c4222","3" -MaxPings 2 | Set-Content c:\temp\test.html
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

Comment: thanks matt for the answer. It was good. But when I am trying to ping that is offline, I am getting this error. Attempted to divide by zero.
At line:38 char:13
+             $props.Success = "{0:p2}" -f ($results.$_.Attempts / $results.$_.Suc ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Comment: @BasatiNaveen I updated to account for that. Looks like I didnt do enough testing.

Comment: Thanks Matt.but I will be happy if it shows the output in html as it if it is showing in my code. I hope we can get that output. Sorry if I am wrong

Comment: You mean with headers for every entry? @BasatiNaveen

Comment: I mean instead of showing 100 times , if it shows single tym with attempts count increasing n showing green n red colors.....just like the output how it shows when we run powershell

Comment: @BasatiNaveen Have a look at what is there now. If you still have issues please so some research on you own first and if you are still stuck then ask a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89212/discussion-between-basati-naveen-and-matt).